# crystal report formula, loop on some data to write them in a single string value

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report, that returns data from a query like follow:

```
Quantity    type
1           cat
2           dogs
5           birds...
```

I want to make a formula to show them in a single string value like:

```
1 cat; 2 dogs; 5 birds;
```

So How to write this formula

Answer (score 1):

```
stringvar A;
A := A & totext({Quantity}, "#") & " " & {type} &";";
A
```

Comment: there is something wrong with it, the data returned is exactly like this:                                                           1 cat;                                                                                                           1 cat; 2 dogs; 5 birds;                                                                                           it duplicate the first item, the first on a the first row, and the other at the next row